# FOR-IN loop that does not trigger due to it's range being not CONTINUOUS in delphi

Tags: delphi, for-in-loop

My problem got simplified after a few days of tearing my hair out (left the important bits only, refer to my many edits for history), here it is:

```
showmessage('i='+inttostr(i));
for i in [2..5,8,11..13] do
showmessage('1');
showmessage('i='+inttostr(i));
```

this is placed in a unit in my program of random fiddling with delphi. I think I should note that non-continuous for-in loop ranges work in the program elsewhere (another unit). In total, I have two such non-continuous `for-in loops` in the same procedure, if I comment out one the other works fine, but if they're both in working condition at the same time, only the second one works, the first one behaves like described below.

First messagebox contains "i= *random-number*" as it's not initialized, not that it needs to be. Messagebox with "1" in it never appears. Second messagebox that appears has "i=14", meaning that the loop did trigger but didnt do anything? That's ridiculous, if not, I want two things if someone can enlighten me:

1) why is this happening?

2) how to fix it and avoid in the future?

Comment: Probably your condition "NOT (somearr[1] as Tcheckbox).checked" never evaluates to true. Please verify if addressing somearr at index 1 is really what you intended.

Comment: Your problem is not in loop, you need verify that somearr has what you  expect.

Comment: If the outer `case` isn't necessary, then please remove it from the test: just loop `for i := 1 to 10 do` instead. Please provide a minimal, but *complete* example that demonstrates the problem. Indicate what you expected to happen, and tell what you observed to happen instead. Replacing the message boxes with simple `WriteLn` calls might make it easier to describe the expected output all at once.

Comment: The moral of all comments: rewrite your question accordingly, that way you will help people help you. Btw, your piece of code doesn't give any information on the initialization value of the variable `j` before entering the outer loop. Read all sections of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to foster your Stackoverflow experience.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. If you did, you could inspect the content of `somearr[1]` and realize it was always the same thing, and that might let you spot that you were using `1` instead of `i` in the test. If `somearr[1]` is checked, the test will pass every time, and therefore there's no reason for the `j` loop to ever execute.

Comment: @David, @Ken, somearr[1..50] has been set in a prior loop to refer to a set of checkboxes (I apoligize if I did not stress that, but if you read not only my code by also explanation that should be obvious), and the checkbox that is refered in somearr[1] (i am using 1 intentionally here) gets toggled by me at run time and has both Checked "false" and "true" values. As already mentioned it triggers without the inner `j` loop weirdly enough, with it - it doesn't.

Comment: @David @Ken, I have edited my question, please read Edit2 portion, both parts of the `if statement` trigger, however the `j loop` in `then` doesn't, even thought a message box before the `j loop` appears, this is most definitelly not an issue with `somearr[1]`

Comment: Can you please add a second ShowMessage after the j loop? Does it show up after you confirmed the first ShowMessage?

Comment: @Uwe, yes it does, a showmessage after the `j loop` shows up, completely skipping the loop as if it was never there, and I do not understand how is that possible

Comment: What data type is i, what version of Delphi do you use, and what compiler flags (range checking, overflow checking) do you have enabled? Your example works as expected on Delphi 2007 for me. Also, if you put a breakpoint on the ShowMessage('1') line, does it ever hit? If not, can you show what the CPU window looks like when a breakpoint on the first ShowMessage hits?

Comment: You've now edited this so many times that it's Community Wiki. That's *not* a good thing, to paraphrase Martha Stewart.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, Delphi2010, `i` is just an integer, I'm running delphi as is out of the box without any additional flags enabled, I'm new and never used breakpoints, I'll give it a go and post something if I manage to make it work... or do something at all.

@Ken, so what would your suggestion be? Do not try to provide more info? Granted maybe not very useful... but I tried... I tried to make a coherent trail of thought and a history of what I tried, and as already mentioned, main issue is in EDIT5, should I scratch it all and just leave the EDIT5 text? That's a bit radical, no?

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, the breakpoint in the loop, at showmessage('1') line indeed never hits, I'm not sure what is the proper or best way to share the copied CPU window (or if what I copied is what I should be showing to begin with), so I hope this works for you: http://pastebin.com/uf465aZB

Comment: This really looks like a code generation bug in your version of the compiler. Unfortunately, I don't have your version available to test with but the code I get in the 2007 version is identical EXCEPT for your statement 16 "add eax,-$10", which I don't have here at all, and there's no good reason it should be there in the 2010 version - it basically subtracts 16 from i before doing the test. It is of course possible that the base used to build the set to test against was changed between the two versions but it is a somewhat unlikely change, I think.

Comment: In any case, it's not working for you due to no fault of yours, IMHO. To verify that, though, please post a complete standalone program that others can compile and run directly.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, thanks a lot for the input. The sad part is I cant reproduce it to save my life. If I make another app with just a button and all of the relevant code with loops copied from the procedure from the original program, they work fine. In fact, even if it's a different unit within my program, the for-in loop appears to function properly. I'll keep trying but I don't think everyone wants to see the whole useless program full of retarded coding...

Answer (score 2):

```
showmessage('i='+inttostr(i));
```

`i` at this point is whatever the random content of memory happens to be at the location allocated to storage for `i`, because you didn't initialize it.

```
for i in [2..5,8,11..13] do
  showmessage('1');
showmessage('i='+inttostr(i));
```

You have something else going on in your code. This works fine in Delphi XE2:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  for j in [2..5,8,11..13] do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('j = %d', [j]));
end;
```

Here's the output from `Memo1`:

[image: Sample output from loop]

There's so much clutter with all of your edits and the leftover noise that you're now saying to ignore that it's hard to see what the problem might be; you've got code that's snipped out, undeclared variables you're accessing, and strange logic that (from what you've included, anyway) make any sense to me.

I think you're spending way too much time on this, though, when a very simple rewrite would help you solve the problem (and IMO be more readable and maintainable in the future, but again that's just IMO):

```
for i := 2 to 13 do
  case i of
    2..5, 8, 11..13:
      ShowMessage(Format('Got i value of %d', [i]));
    else:
      ShowMessage(Format('Got other value of %d', [i]));
  end;
```

As far as you're seeing the value of `i` count downward from 50 to 1 in the other loop, this is a known issue when viewing loop counters in the debugger; it has to do with code optimizations that confuse the debugger's evaluator. It's been a well-known (and often discussed in the Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero newsgroups) behavior since Delphi 1, and only affects the display in the debugger; it's guaranteed not to affect the behavior of your code's actual execution results.

Comment: Thanks for that last bit about it counting down, I'm relatively knew so I didnt know that. Edits are chronological and I didnt edit anything in any previous text (unless it something trivial, like grammar/formatting). From start to finish it's showing what I've been trying to do, what ideas I had, what I've tested etc, the whole trail of thought, however my issue now is contained in Edit5 only, that's the core issue. My apologies if it was confusing. I have stressed that *it works* for me if it's placed somewhere else. What I have now appears to be a conflict between two FOR-IN loops.

Comment: Raith, since this site is like a wiki, it includes an *edit history* of every post. People interested in seeing what a previous version of a question looked like can see it. Please *delete* an irrelevant information from your question. Historians can look at the edit history if they care about the obsolete versions. Primarily, consider the many people who will visit this page *later* and won't care about your original confused question. They'll want to get straight to the point, so don't make them wade through all your edits.

Comment: Good point, I was aware of the edits history. Thank you and done.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I tested your code on Delphi 2006 and Xe2 and in both cases is working fine; looks to me there may be a prior problem that could be trashing the memory, maybe something related to a variable or the check-boxes array; once I had the case (using Delphi6) were I had to to initializate J before the loop, I did something like:

```
procedure MyTestFunc();
var
i, j: integer;
begin
  memo1.lines.clear;
  for i:= 1 to 50 do
  Begin
    case i of
      1..10:
        if NOT (somearr[1] as Tcheckbox).checked then
        Begin
            j:=0;
            for j in [2..5,7,11..13] do
            begin
                memo1.Lines.Add('j= '+inttostr(j));
                (somearr[j] as Tcheckbox).Checked := false;
            end
        end
        else memo1.Lines.Add('false');
      11..20:BEgin
           End;
    End;
  End;
end;
```

I never been able to understand why that fixed it. you can always do step through debugging and inspect each variable.

If you need more help you can post more code so we can help you to address better this issue.

good luck!